# Clone queues and exchange from multiple virtual host into one in rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

Is there a way to copy all queues and exchanges from multiple virtual hosts into a new single virtual host in rabbitmq?

Comment: Would you like to copy the queues themselves or just their contents (messages)?

Comment: just queues and exchanges, do not need content